# How to increase timeout of DataAdapter to 3 min?

Tags: c#, sql-server, timeout

When i execute a query with the following method, i get a timeout.

So my question is: how can i set the timeout to 180 seconds?

I'm using the connection to fill the dataSet with the queryresult.

```
 internal static DataSet executeQuery(string queryString)
 {
     // #connection
     DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
     string connectionString = Connection.connectionStringSQL01NavProvider();
     OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
     OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, connectionString);

     // Open the connection and fill the DataSet. 
     connection.Open();
     try
     {
         adapter.Fill(dataSet);
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         dt = dataSet.Tables[0];
         DataRow dr;
         try
         {
             dr = dt.Rows[0];
         }
         catch 
         {

         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error executeQuery().! " + ex.Message);
     }

     return dataSet;
 }
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can set the [`CommandTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) of the [`SelectCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.selectcommand(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 180; // default is 30 seconds
```

If you can't establish a connection to the database and you also want to increase that timeout, you have to do that in the connection-string, for example(default is 15 seconds):

```
"Data Source=(local);Connection Timeout=30;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

---

Note that you should use the `using`-statement for your connection and other objects implementing `IDisposable` like the `OleDbDataAdapter`. On that way you ensure that all unmanaged resources are disposed properly:

```
internal static DataSet executeQuery(string queryString)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    string connectionString = Connection.connectionStringSQL01NavProvider();
    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    using(var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            adapter.Fill(dataSet); // you dont need to open/close the connection with Fill
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error executeQuery().! " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    return dataSet;
}
```

Comment: FYI - connection.ConnectionTimeout = 180; does not work because it is read-only.  Maybe this has changed over time, not sure.

Comment: Since it is read only, this one worked for me: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13009/Accesing-CommandTimeout-properties-in-a-TableAdapt