# Executing SQL command works in SQL but not in .C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, sqldataadapter

I have a quite large SQL query that works as expected when i´m exceuting it in MS SQL. However when I run it from C# it does not fetch any rows (dataTable does not return any rows). If I instead use a simple query, for e.g. "SELECT * Accounts FROM TableX" from C#, dataTable returns all the rows it should do. I also tried to remove all the spaces from the SQL query so everything was on the same line, but without any change. Here is the code:

```
internal void GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionBuilder.ToString())) //1. Open connection
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(GetSqlString(), connection))
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
                    {
                        var field1 = dataRow[0];
                        var field2 = dataRow[1];
                        Logger.Log(field1 + " " + field2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            utilityProvider.Log("Error" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private string GetSqlString()
    {

        return @"SELECT 
        Field1 = subscr.cind_recipient,

        Field2 = COALESCE(
                a.name, s.cind_name, 
                    CASE WHEN c.cind_is_protected_identity = 0 THEN c.fullname 
                    ELSE ISNULL(c.cind_protected_firstname, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(c.cind_protected_lastname, '') END ), 

        Field3 = COALESCE(CASE WHEN c.cind_is_protected_identity <> 1 THEN c.address1_line3 
            ELSE c.cind_protected_address1_line3 END,
                 s.cind_postal_line3),

        Field4 = COALESCE(CASE WHEN c.cind_is_protected_identity = 0 THEN c.address1_line1 
            ELSE c.cind_protected_address1_line1 END,
                               a.address2_line1, s.cind_postal_line1),

        Field5 = COALESCE(CASE WHEN c.cind_is_protected_identity = 0 THEN c.address1_line2 
            ELSE c.cind_protected_address1_line2 END, 
                               a.address2_line2, s.cind_postal_line2),

        Field6 = COALESCE(CASE WHEN c.cind_is_protected_identity = 0 THEN mpc1.cind_postalcode 
            ELSE mpc.cind_postalcode END,
                            a.address1_postalcode, s.cind_postal_postalcode),

        Field7 = COALESCE(CASE WHEN c.cind_is_protected_identity = 0 THEN mpc1.cind_city 
            ELSE mpc.cind_city END, 
                          a.address1_city, s.cind_postal_city),

        Field8 = c.cind_member_number,

        Field9 = ISNULL(COALESCE(c.cind_union_section_idname, a.cind_mml_mub_union_section_idname), a1.cind_mml_mub_union_section_idname),

        Field10 = CASE WHEN c.cind_is_protected_identity <> 1 THEN c.cind_soc_sec_no 
            ELSE c.cind_protected_cind_soc_sec_no END,

        Field11 = COALESCE(a.cind_organization_no, s.cind_organization_no),
        Field12 = c.gendercodename,
        Field13 = cind_count,
        Field14 = k1.cind_name,
        Field15 = k1.cind_number,
        Field16 = k2.cind_name,
        Field17 = k2.cind_number,
        Field18 = 'sam',
        Field19 = subscr.villa_free_exname

        FROM dbo.Filteredcind_mml_mub_subscription subscr

        INNER JOIN Filteredcind_mml_mub_service svc
            ON subscr.cind_mml_mub_service_id = svc.cind_mml_mub_serviceid
                AND svc.cind_code = 'PE002'

        LEFT JOIN Filteredcind_mml_mub_site s
            ON subscr.cind_mml_mub_site_id = s.cind_mml_mub_siteid

        LEFT JOIN FilteredAccount a
            ON subscr.cind_account_id = a.accountid

        LEFT JOIN  FilteredAccount a1 
            ON a1.accountid = s.cind_account_id

        INNER JOIN FilteredContact c
            ON subscr.cind_contact_id = c.contactid
                AND c.statecode = 0

        LEFT JOIN Filteredcind_mml_mub_postalcity mpc
            ON c.cind_protected_cind_postalcity_id = mpc.cind_mml_mub_postalcityid

        LEFT JOIN Filteredcind_mml_mub_postalcity mpc1
            ON c.cind_postalcity_id = mpc1.cind_mml_mub_postalcityid

        LEFT JOIN Filteredcind_mml_mub_county lan
            ON  c.cind_county_id = lan.cind_mml_mub_countyid

        LEFT JOIN Filteredcind_mml_mub_country land
            ON lan.cind_country_id = land.cind_mml_mub_countryid

        LEFT JOIN (Filteredcind_mml_mub_membership m1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT mt1.cind_mml_mub_membership_typeid
                        FROM Filteredcind_mml_mub_membership_type mt1
                        WHERE mt1.cind_code = 'PRDI-45') mtt1
                        ON mtt1.cind_mml_mub_membership_typeid = m1.cind_mml_mub_membership_type_id)
            ON c.contactid = m1.cind_contact_id
            AND (m1.statuscode = 1
                OR m1.statuscode = 434578)
            AND m1.statecode = 0

        LEFT JOIN Filteredcind_mml_mub_local_union k1
            ON m1.cind_mml_mub_local_union_id = k1.cind_mml_mub_local_unionid

        LEFT JOIN (Filteredcind_mml_mub_membership m2
            INNER JOIN (SELECT mt2.cind_mml_mub_membership_typeid
                        FROM Filteredcind_mml_mub_membership_type mt2
                        WHERE mt2.cind_code = 'EXTR-01') mtt2
                        ON mtt2.cind_mml_mub_membership_typeid = m2.cind_mml_mub_membership_type_id)
            ON c.contactid = m2.cind_contact_id
            AND (m2.statuscode = 1
                OR m2.statuscode = 126670001)
            AND m2.statecode = 0

        LEFT JOIN Filteredcind_mml_mub_local_union k2
            ON m2.cind_mml_mub_local_union_id = k2.cind_mml_mub_local_unionid

        WHERE subscr.statuscode = 1
            AND subscr.statecode = 0";
    }
```

Comment: It could be a timeout issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910016/how-to-increase-timeout-of-dataadapter-to-3-min

Comment: Connect to the `Sql Server` instance with `Sql Profiler`. Observe the query being sent to the server and copy it from there. Now paste it in your SSMS and re-execute. If the results are the same (no results returned) then its a problem with the query itself. If the results are different then you are probably not connecting to the same instance or to a different schema.

Comment: Did you tried executing profiler query again in SSMS? What was the output?

Comment: OK. I will try tonight or tomrrow morning.

Comment: @Igor. Thanks for your reply. I tried Sql profiler as you described, however the query that shows up there works in MS SQL without any problems.

Im using the same schema.

Comment: @KannanKandasamy see above

Comment: In Sql Profiler you can gather info including 1) **RowCounts** (#records returned) 2) **DatabaseID** (not name) 3) **TextData** (query) 4) **LoginName**. Run the query from SSMS and also from your app and capture these results in Profiler and find where the difference(s) are.

Answer (score 0):

If `SELECT *` works then its likely to be a timeout issue. However you should be receiving an exception.

The default timeout is 30 seconds.

How long does it take your query to run in MSSQL?

change the timeout by setting

```
cmd.Timeout = 300; // Change the number of seconds.
```

Alternatively improve the efficiency of your query.

Comment: I think the problem is not about timeout because, he was not faced timeout exception. i think,he had not even run its query.

Comment: @Mr.AF Correct.

Comment: @CathalMF Thanks. But it made no difference.

Comment: @kranis100 well then your problem must be the SQL query, it cannot be the same as what you are running in mssql because the rest of your code is fine.

Comment: @CathalMF I tried with SQL profiler and the query that the DB recieves is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your SQL line by line then you'll find the problem. Start with dropping all column, use * instead (as CathalMF said), then drop the joins, one by one.