# Command timeout in script task C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

I get this timeout error:

> Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Script task executes stored procedure that takes some time. If I change parameter in a stored procedure to retrieve less data then it works fine. So I am assuming I have to increase the connection timeout in my code. But I don't know where exactly should I do that?

I tried to change `Connect Timeout` in connection manager - but it didn't help.

[image]

I also tried this:

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 500;
```

But still - no success.

I guess I need to do that somewhere in a code:

```
public void Main()
        {
            string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).AddDays(1 - DateTime.Now.Day);
            DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
            //var now = DateTime.Now;
            //var firstDayCurrentMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
            //var lastDayLastMonth = firstDayCurrentMonth.AddDays(-1);
            try
            {
                //Declare Variables

                // string ExcelFileName = Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString() +" "+ String.Format("{0:M-d-yyyy}", endDate);
                string ExcelFileName = Dts.Variables["User::NewExcelFileName"].Value.ToString();
                string FolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
                string StoredProcedureName = Dts.Variables["User::StoredProcedureName"].Value.ToString();
                string SheetName = Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value.ToString();
                string connStringDB = "MyConnString";
                string excelConn = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}{1};Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';", FolderPath, ExcelFileName);

                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStringDB))
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedureName, conn)

                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                })
                {
                    conn.Open();


                    string queryString = String.Format("EXEC {0}", StoredProcedureName);

                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, conn);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(ds);

                    //Get Header Columns
                    string TableColumns = "";
                    // Get the Column List from Data Table so can create Excel Sheet with Header
                    foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                        {
                            TableColumns += column + "],[";
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();

                    // Replace most right comma from Columnlist
                    //TableColumns = ("[" + TableColumns.Replace(",", " Text,").TrimEnd(','));
                    TableColumns = ("[" + TableColumns.Replace(",", " text,").TrimEnd(','));
                    TableColumns = TableColumns.Remove(TableColumns.Length - 2);

                    //Use OLE DB Connection and Create Excel Sheet
                    using (OleDbConnection connODB = new OleDbConnection(excelConn))
                    {
                        connODB.Open();
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                        cmd.Connection = connODB;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 500; //Entered by Oleg

                        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("Create table {0} ({1})", SheetName, TableColumns);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                        {
                            String sqlCommandInsert = "";
                            String sqlCommandValue = "";
                            foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
                            {
                                sqlCommandValue += dataColumn + "],[";
                            }

                            sqlCommandValue = "[" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',');
                            sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Remove(sqlCommandValue.Length - 2);
                            sqlCommandInsert = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES (", SheetName, sqlCommandValue);
                            int columnCount = table.Columns.Count;
                            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                            {
                                string columnvalues = "";
                                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                                {
                                    int index = table.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                                    var a = table.Rows[index].ItemArray[i].ToString().Replace("'", "''");
                                    columnvalues += "'" + a + "',";
                                    //columnvalues += "'" + table.Rows[index].ItemArray[i] + "',";

                                }
                                columnvalues = columnvalues.TrimEnd(',');
                                var command2 = sqlCommandInsert + columnvalues + ")";
                                cmd.CommandText = command2;
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }

                        }
                        conn.Close();
                    }


                }

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                // Create Log File for Errors
                using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" +
                    Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString() + datetime + ".log"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

                }
            }
        }
    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: I had similar issue and had to do it directly in the C# script because the connection didnt set timeout properly from the setting you did above, but I dont see your issue, you have connection.timeout in the c# task already, that should be working?

Comment: Yes, that doesnt work also.

Comment: Doing it that way worked for me but I was not using ADO.  Maybe you need to make it higher, maybe make it huge for testing to confirm.  Also do you know where/what part of the code and what connection is causing the timeout?  Did you try debugging?  Add a MessageBox.Show to your error/catch block (for debugging only, since debugging in SSIS sucks).  You can also try adding timeout directly to your connection string:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: you have to set the SQLadapter command timeout: `adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;`, check my answer update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the Command Timeout to `0` instead of `500`

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

And also you have to set the SQLAdapter timeout:

```
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

Based on the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> A value of 0 indicates no limit (an attempt to execute a command will wait indefinitely).

You code should look like:

```
public void Main()
        {
            string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).AddDays(1 - DateTime.Now.Day);
            DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
            //var now = DateTime.Now;
            //var firstDayCurrentMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
            //var lastDayLastMonth = firstDayCurrentMonth.AddDays(-1);
            try
            {
                //Declare Variables

                // string ExcelFileName = Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString() +" "+ String.Format("{0:M-d-yyyy}", endDate);
                string ExcelFileName = Dts.Variables["User::NewExcelFileName"].Value.ToString();
                string FolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString();
                string StoredProcedureName = Dts.Variables["User::StoredProcedureName"].Value.ToString();
                string SheetName = Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value.ToString();
                string connStringDB = "MyConnString";
                string excelConn = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}{1};Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';", FolderPath, ExcelFileName);

                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStringDB))
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedureName, conn)

                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                })
                {
                    conn.Open();


                    string queryString = String.Format("EXEC {0}", StoredProcedureName);

                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, conn);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    adapter.Fill(ds);

                    //Get Header Columns
                    string TableColumns = "";
                    // Get the Column List from Data Table so can create Excel Sheet with Header
                    foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                    {
                        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                        {
                            TableColumns += column + "],[";
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();

                    // Replace most right comma from Columnlist
                    //TableColumns = ("[" + TableColumns.Replace(",", " Text,").TrimEnd(','));
                    TableColumns = ("[" + TableColumns.Replace(",", " text,").TrimEnd(','));
                    TableColumns = TableColumns.Remove(TableColumns.Length - 2);

                    //Use OLE DB Connection and Create Excel Sheet
                    using (OleDbConnection connODB = new OleDbConnection(excelConn))
                    {
                        connODB.Open();
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                        cmd.Connection = connODB;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0; //Entered by Oleg

                        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("Create table {0} ({1})", SheetName, TableColumns);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                        {
                            String sqlCommandInsert = "";
                            String sqlCommandValue = "";
                            foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in table.Columns)
                            {
                                sqlCommandValue += dataColumn + "],[";
                            }

                            sqlCommandValue = "[" + sqlCommandValue.TrimEnd(',');
                            sqlCommandValue = sqlCommandValue.Remove(sqlCommandValue.Length - 2);
                            sqlCommandInsert = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES (", SheetName, sqlCommandValue);
                            int columnCount = table.Columns.Count;
                            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                            {
                                string columnvalues = "";
                                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                                {
                                    int index = table.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                                    var a = table.Rows[index].ItemArray[i].ToString().Replace("'", "''");
                                    columnvalues += "'" + a + "',";
                                    //columnvalues += "'" + table.Rows[index].ItemArray[i] + "',";

                                }
                                columnvalues = columnvalues.TrimEnd(',');
                                var command2 = sqlCommandInsert + columnvalues + ")";
                                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                                cmd.CommandText = command2;
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }

                        }
                        conn.Close();
                    }


                }

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                // Create Log File for Errors
                using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" +
                    Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFileName"].Value.ToString() + datetime + ".log"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;

                }
            }
        }
    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

**Reference**

- [How to increase timeout of DataAdapter to 3 min?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910016/how-to-increase-timeout-of-dataadapter-to-3-min)

Comment: Awesome! Works. Thank you!